# Authenticate with Google Python SDK with only auth_token or the refresh_token

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I have bunch of gmail.storage files containing a JSON blob with access info for users' accounts. I got these credential sets using PHP to prompt the user to authenticate/authorize my app. I'm able to call the Gmail API using these credentials. The JSON has the following fields:

```
{"access_token": xxxxxx,
"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":3599,
"refresh_token":"xxxxxx",
"created":1421545394}
```

However, when I use the Python SDK for Gmail to authenticate a call using these credentials file like so:

```
 credentials = storage.get()
```

It says that it needs the fields `_module`, `_class` and a few others. I'm able to get these when I use Python to fetch the information but not with PHP. Any idea how I can use the above code to get credentials without these extraneous fields?

Answer (score 0):

Just call the refresh method before using the creds again.

```
storage = file.Storage("auth.dat")
credentials = storage.get()

http = httplib2.Http()
credentials.refresh(http)   # <----------
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('whatever_service', 'v2', http=http)
```